# AWS's EC2 doesn't scale on all available zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have configured an AWS auto-scale group with 2 available zones: us-east-1a and us-east-1c . Today, with the issue AWS had on us-east-1a, I noticed that new instances are not created on us-east-1c zone.

Any clues on what I should check on?

Thank you.

Comment: AWS S3 and EC2 had service issues this morning. They are resolved now. Try after one hour.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I would like to have it use a different region if this case happens again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling can deploy EC2 instances across multiple Availability Zones within one region.

It cannot deploy instances across multiple Availability Zones.

If you wish to implement redundancy across regions, you would need to configure Amazon Route 53 with a health check to route traffic to instances or load balancers in different regions. However, Auto Scaling would continue to operate independently in each region.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.If I have 2 zones configures on Auto Scaling (us-east-1a and us-east-1c) and us-east-1a is down, new instances should not be created on us-east-1c and thus avoid downtime?

Comment: Auto Scaling will work to give you the **Desired Capacity** that you have requested. So, if you have configured two AZs with a desired capacity of 2 instances, it will give you one instance in each AZ. If one of those AZs fails, then it will launch an additional instance in the remaining AZ to continue giving you the desired capacity of 2 instances.

Comment: Thank you! What I dont know is why my config kept launching east-1a instances instead of east-1c even though east-1a was down.